# Android: Pull SwipeRefreshLayout from left to refresh

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I am using a horizontol recyclerview inside a SwipeRefreshLayout. Is it possible for me to activate the refresh on the recycler view by pulling from left to right instead of top to bottom ? A question already exists but there are no solutions on that.

Comment: You need to customize it . Take reference from https://github.com/ashakirov/Horizontal-SwipeRefreshLayout.

Comment: I am surprised the Android team did not customize it.

Comment: No need to surprise Good things take time .However Swipe left to right seems awkward to me right now. Maybe its because i haven't seen it in any app yet . If you think of geometry of mobile device and user touch then this will be an awkward action too.  anyway you are good to go with the above link .

Comment: Well, I am making a social media app where posts appear on pages. Since it is hard for me to implement the page turning animation, for now, I just wanted an infinite left to right scrolling.